# Prometheus - calculate percentage of 503 error count, per API using PromQL

Tags: prometheus, metrics, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

Let say I have following time series followed by total count of status code -

app_interface_statusCode{instance="localhost:5555", job="prometheus", metricType="Count", service="myItemService.200"} -> 1

app_interface_statusCode{instance="localhost:5555", job="prometheus", metricType="Count", service="myItemService.400"} -> 4

app_interface_statusCode{instance="localhost:5555", job="prometheus", metricType="Count", service="myItemService.404"} -> 1

app_interface_statusCode{instance="localhost:5555", job="prometheus", metricType="Count", service="myItemService.500"} -> 3

app_interface_statusCode{instance="localhost:5555", job="prometheus", metricType="Count", service="myItemService.503"} -> 3

app_interface_statusCode{instance="localhost:5555", job="prometheus", metricType="Count", service="myShopService.200"} -> 2

app_interface_statusCode{instance="localhost:5555", job="prometheus", metricType="Count", service="myShopService.400"} -> 4

app_interface_statusCode{instance="localhost:5555", job="prometheus", metricType="Count", service="myShopService.404"} -> 1

app_interface_statusCode{instance="localhost:5555", job="prometheus", metricType="Count", service="myShopService.500"} -> 2

app_interface_statusCode{instance="localhost:5555", job="prometheus", metricType="Count", service="myShopService.503"} -> 6

If you notice the metric, there are basically two API named as myItemService and myShopService. I have the count of status code. Now I want to calculate the percentage of 503 error, **per API** and set an alert if the percentage is grater than a specific threshold using promQL.

Let say, the threshold is **30**. I wanna trigger alert if the **percentage of 503 count for any of the API is greater than 30**.

According to above metric,

total request in myItemService api = 12

total 503 in myItemService = 3

myItemService percentage = 3/12*100 = 25

total request in myShopService api = 15

total 503 in myShopService = 6

myShopService percentage = 6/15*100 = 40

For the above scenario, alert should trigger for myShopService API.

**Questions:**

1. According to my metric structure, can I calculate percentage of 503 **per API**? If yes, what will be the promQL query?
   I prepared the following promQL but it is giving me the result considering whole, not per API

   sum(app_interface_statusCode{metricType="Count", service=~".*503"})  / sum(app_interface_statusCode{metricType="Count"}) * 100
2. Can I split the API name and status code in the time series?
   For example: In my existing time series,

as you can see -

service="myItemService.503"

Can I make the time series like -

app_interface_statusCode{instance="localhost:5555", job="prometheus", metricType="Count", service="myItemService", statusCode="503"}

if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query extracts status code from `service` label into the `statusCode` label by using the [label_replace](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function:

```
label_replace(app_interface_statusCode, "statusCode", "$1", "service", "[^.]+\\.([0-9]+)")
```

The following query removes the status code part from the `service` label:

```
label_replace(app_interface_statusCode, "service", "$1", "service", "([^.]+)\\.[0-9]+")
```

Now let's combine these two queries in order to obtain `service` label without status code and the status code in the `statusCode` label:

```
label_replace(
  label_replace(app_interface_statusCode, "statusCode", "$1", "service", "[^.]+\\.([0-9]+)"),
  "service", "$1", "service", "([^.]+)\\.[0-9]+"
)
```

The following query calculates the per-service percentage of requests with 503 status codes if `q` returns time series with properly set `service` and `statusCode` labels:

```
sum(q{statusCode="503"}) by (service) / sum(q) by (service)
```

This query uses [sum() function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) for summing metrics with identical `service` label.

Unfortunately the `q` cannot be replaced with the big `label_replace()` query above, since [label filters](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#filtering) cannot be applied to time series returned from functions :(

So we have to rewrite `statusCode="503"` filter into filter on the original `service` label containing both service name and status code:

```
label_replace(
  label_replace(app_interface_statusCode{service=~"[^.]+\\.503"}, "statusCode", "$1", "service", "[^.]+\\.([0-9]+)"),
  "service", "$1", "service", "([^.]+)\\.[0-9]+"
)
```

Then the final query converts into the following monster:

```
sum(
  label_replace(
    label_replace(app_interface_statusCode{service=~"[^.]+\\.503"}, "statusCode", "$1", "service", "[^.]+\\.([0-9]+)"),
    "service", "$1", "service", "([^.]+)\\.[0-9]+"
  )
) by (service)
  /
sum(
  label_replace(app_interface_statusCode, "service", "$1", "service", "([^.]+)\\.[0-9]+")
) by (service)
```

P.S. As you can see, it is better to store time series with properly formatted labels instead of relying on `label_replace()` function for label formatting during query time, since this may significantly simplify the final query. That's why it is recommended to use [relabeling](https://valyala.medium.com/how-to-use-relabeling-in-prometheus-and-victoriametrics-8b90fc22c4b2) at data ingestion time. See also [this relabeling cookbook](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/relabeling.html).